# Why is the value of "$?" changed in the "if" condition?

Tags: linux, shell, command, return-value, exit-code

I'm confused by the the value of "$?" in my shell script. I wrote a demo script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "good"
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
  echo "$? not equal 0"
else
  echo "$? equal 0"
fi

echo "good"
ret=$?
if [ $ret -ne 0 ];then
  echo "$ret not equal 0"
else
  echo "$ret equal 0"
fi
```

I know,"$?" is used to save the return value of the last function or command, but why is the output as below?

```
good 
1 equal 0

good
0 equal 0
```

Does it mean that `[ $? -eq 0 ]` is also a command or function? I'm puzzled!

Comment: Because even `[ $? -ne 0 ]` is an expression which is evaluated and status is placed in the `$?` after the excecution

Comment: For the record, an idiomatic shell script should almost never need to examine `$?`.  The usual syntax is simply `if echo good; then echo "$? equal 0"; else echo "$? not equal to 0"; fi`.  You'll notice that this also preserves the value of `$?` to the inside of the conditional.

Comment: yeah,but sometimes it is useful.thanks all very much

Answer (score 0):

Your original code could be rewritten as:

```
$ if echo "good"; then echo "$? equal 0"; fi
good
0 equal 0
```

Since your code is only checking the exit value of the echo command, it's almost always going to return 0 (e.g. "true") unless its file descriptor is closed. For example:

```
$ echo foo; echo $?
foo
0

$ echo bar >&- ; echo $?
-bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
1
```

Comment: thanks for your help and i understand your example,but what i am still beening confused is why the value of $? changed in the first test script? And as your say, if it means its origin file descriptor is closed after the condition  " if [ $? -ne 0 ];then..."  ? thanks a lot